# Docker Communicate between two containers (VSCode Remote containers)

Tags: docker, vscode-remote

I have two separate apps running on Docker, both are using VSCode's remote containers. Separate docker-compose files. I'm trying to have one container communicate with the other via an http request but it isn't working as intended.

Container 1: `localhost:3000` trying to connect to container 2's `localhost:8080`. I'm pretty sure I'm missing some config here. They're in separate containers so the "localhost" is of different domains. But is it possible to make the two communicate, somehow?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **host.docker.internal** as a functioning alias for localhost. Then use this string inside your containers to access your host machine.

Let me give a [Link](https://www.howtogeek.com/devops/how-to-connect-to-localhost-within-a-docker-container/) which will help you to configure